# Setup ITHit WebDAV server with MySQL

Tags: java, webdav

I have downloaded the ITHit WebDAV server (java version) and wanted to know if there is any examples/documentation on implementing this with MySQL (both examples are for Oracle) database or for simple file system based storage.

Since I'm just getting started ANY additional documentation or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you simply not change the database URL and DriverName for the appropriate mySql version, as if you create mySql JDBC connection?

Comment: Have you looked at milton.io? Its more widely used then ithit and very actively supported and maintained. It has a filesystem example - https://github.com/miltonio/milton2/tree/master/milton-server-ce/src/main/java/io/milton/http/fs - and I'd be happy to provide a fully worked mysql tutorial for milton

Comment: I just looked at miltion.io webpage and while interesting, fully 1/2 the links on the page don't work so my confidence isn't really high.  I guess I would need to know a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

We have MySql sample and use it internally for testing purposes. Please write us and we will send it to you. We do not publish it because it duplicates most of the Oracle sample code.

Currently there is no any examples other then with Oracle provided with IT Hit WebDAV Server Library for Java. We are working to create more samples.

The main reason why we do not create a sample with file system is that to store file locks we need to create external files. This may clatter your storage.

In case of the file system sample for WebDAV Server Engine for .Net we store locks in NTFS alternate file streams, so there is no any extra files are created in file system. With Java is more difficult, and probably goes outside of the idea of the 'Sample'.